# How do I use the English index in Gesenius's Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon?

Tags: hebrew, angels, tools-of-biblical-studies

Recently acquired the book Gesenius's Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon, from H. W. F. Geneius.

While trying to search the word angel, I've gone to the English index and, associated with angel, could read the following

[image: English index]

The page layout looks like this (had to reduce image's quality due to upload size limits but I think you get the idea)
[image: Page layout]

There's both page numbers and side numbers.

I checked what's in 49 both page and side number and 475.

One other way I could think of was to go to biblehub and found the word for angel is [malak](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/4397.htm), מַלְאַךְ. From here, tried to find the word but it's hard to spot it manually in the middle of all the words with no understanding of the language. One thing I've noticed is that from page to page the words keep the same last characters (reading from left to the right). This didn't take me anywhere yet.

What can / should I do to find the information about angel in a more efficient way?

Comment: Blue Letter Bible.org has the Gesenius entry as well as all the verses where H4397 (malak) appears. https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H4397&t=KJV   ---   As for the book, maybe look for "4397" in the margins and that may make sense of the index page numbers. The index should be page # (bottom of page) and "a" or "b" is the column where entry will be found.

Comment: You're right, 4397!

Comment: Still don't know how you took that number from the index though...

Comment: But can see that number in biblehub and in blueletterhub.

Comment: I have the book, but not with me. Do you see the page number at the *bottom* of the page?  The numbers at top of page are Strong's numbers. Index goes by page, not Strong's #.

Comment: Feel free to answer with that information. I'll edit to improve including an image. Thank you @tblue

Comment: You're welcome. But won't place as an answer as I don't think your ques. fits BH rules. Surprised it hasn't been voted to close. If you start getting negative votes, just delete the question (since no answers are attached yet).

Comment: Hebrew "malak" means messenger.  Greek "aggelos" means messenger.  Can be either the heavenly messengers - Gabriel, Michael, etc who r "mightier in power"; or earth born messengers such as the prophets (Malachi), Jesus (Yeshua), JOhn, the apostles, etc.  But, this ? is not about a particular scripture.  Can you rephrase to include a verse from the Bible? Otherwise, should close this one.

Comment: @Gina this question isn't about a specific verse, sorry...

Comment: @tblue We do allow some questions about the [tools used by biblical scholars](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/what-should-we-do-with-questions-about-tools-used-in-biblical-scholarship)

Comment: @Soldarnal Yes. I don't think this deserves to be closed, myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second image, the side number corresponds to the Strong’s number. For example, 477 is H477, which is the Hebrew Strong’s number for אֱלִישָׁע.

The bottom number in the second image is the actual page number. In the second image, you were on p. 52.

In the first image, it says,

> angel, 49a, 475a

This means that the equivalent Hebrew word(s) for the English word “angel” will be located on p. 49 of the lexicon, left column (i.e., column A), as well as on p. 475, also on the left column.

So, going to p. 49, left column, what Hebrew word do you find that corresponds to the English word “angel”? My guess would be אלהים. Let’s see.

Using Tregelles’ English translation (1860) of Gesenius’ lexicon (see **References** below), going to p. [49](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR49#v=onepage&q&f=false) (XLIX), left column, we find mention of “angels” under the word אֱלוֹהַּ (*eloah*), and then under the section for אֱלֹהִים (*elohim*):

[image]

And, on p. [475](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR475#v=onepage&q&f=false) (CCCCLXXV), left column, I am sure we will find the Hebrew word מלאך (*malakh*) which is the Hebrew word most often translated into English as “angel.”

[image]

---

**References**

Gesenius, Heinrich Friedrich Wilhelm. [*Gesenius’s Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ) Trans. Tregelles, Samuel Prideaux. London: Bagster, 1860.