# Who is the fourth man in Daniel 3:25?

Tags: angels, daniel

In Daniel 3:25 says:

> 25 He answered and said, Lo, I see four men loose, walking in the midst of the fire, and they have no hurt; and the form of the fourth is like the Son of God. (KJV)

*Is this man Jesus?* I'm having trouble understanding this because in the RVR60 version (spanish) it says (emphasis mine):

> 25 Y él dijo: He aquí yo veo cuatro varones sueltos, que se pasean en medio del fuego sin sufrir ningún daño; y el aspecto del cuarto es semejante **al hijo de los dioses**. (RVR60)

Meaning "like the son of the gods"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**John Calvin** considered the possibility that the fourth man was Christ, but settled on identifying the man as an angel instead.

See https://biblehub.com/commentaries/calvin/daniel/3.htm

**Charles Spurgeon** preached that the fourth man was the pre-incarnate Christ:

See https://www.spurgeon.org/resource-library/sermons/consolation-in-the-furnace#flipbook/

An excerpt:

> V. The last and perhaps the most pleasing part of the text is,  WHO WAS WITH THEM IN THE FURNACE.
>
> There was a fourth, and he was so bright and glorious,  that even the
>   heathen eyes of Nebuchadnezzar could discern a supernatural lustre
>   about him. “The fourth,” he said, “is like the Son of God.” What
>   appearance Christ had put on I cannot tell, which was recognizable by
>   that heathen monarch; but I suppose that he appeared in a degree of
>   that glory in which he showed himself to his servant John in the
>   Apocalypse, and such was the excessive splendour and brightness, the
>   God-like air that was about him, the flash of his eye and the
>   splendour of his gait as he walked the fire with the other three, that
>   even Nebuchadnezzar could not help saying he was like the Son of God.

**Barnes' Commentary**

See https://www.godtube.com/bible/daniel/3-25

Barnes argues that the original Chaldee did not include the definite article "the", suggesting "a Son of God" not "The Son of God". But he also comments on the popularity among scholars of the view that this was a Christophany:

> Was it an angel, or was it the second person of the Trinity, "the" Son
>   of God? That this was the Son of God - the second person of the
>   Trinity, who afterward became incarnate, has been quite a common
>   opinion of expositors. So it was held by **Tertullian**, by **Augustine**, and
>   by **Hilary**, among the fathers; and so it has been held by **Gill**,
>   **Clarius**, and others, among the moderns.

I imagine that many other theologians have come to opposite opinions on this.

Comment: I've found that also Jonathan Edwards preached that it was a Christophany, and also many theologicians claims that "the angel of God" is a Christophany

Comment: Between Calvin, Spurgeon and Jonathan Edwards is a balanced view, of a mysterious manifestation that would suggest something to us but that cannot be dogmatically asserted. How valuable to have many counsellors. Proverbs 11:14.

Answer (score 2):

As we read later in **Daniel 3:28**, that other person is "an angel".

> Then Nebuchadnezzar spake, and said, Blessed be the God of Shadrach,
>   Meshach, and Abednego, who hath sent his angel, and delivered his
>   servants that trusted in him, and have changed the king's word, and
>   yielded their bodies, that they might not serve nor worship any god,
>   except their own God.

Comment: Is there a difference between "his (God's) angel" and "an angel"?

Comment: The precise identity of the angel of the Lord is not given in the Bible. In this case it's only used `מַלְאֲכֵהּ֙ | mal·’ă·ḵêh`, so it's not about the angel of the Lord and rather a normal angel.

Comment: Do you know if there is a term for `malakh` in Aramaic (the original language of this scripture)?

Comment: For מַלְאַך (malak) you have [here](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/strongs_4398.htm).

Comment: [Was reading it some days ago](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/45254/27054).